# getFinalPrice: Not displaying correct international prices

Tags: php, magento, internationalization, currency

I need to display prices on my site's catalog/list layout, and am using this:

```
<?php echo number_format($_product->getFinalPrice(), 2) ?>
```

The site needs to display different prices for Australia and Japan. The correct prices are shown when I am looking at the product page, but when I go to the catalog/list layout where I am using the (above) PHP call it displays the original prices. It needs to display the Japanese prices, not the original prices.

Could someone please help with this issue, I have spent days trying to figure this one out but cannot find a solution.

Comment: Why don't you use generic `$this->getPriceHtml($_product, true)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Will you change the default currency option from admin or not?

do one thing go to admin side click on system=>configuration=>currency setup (in configuration tab)

now set Default Display Currency option as per your requirement. and check it if it's working or not?

Hope it will help you